# Specified months previous month data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to display data of specified month and year's previous month's data.

Example : My input is December 2014 and i want to display November 2014 data.

I have table userBalance with fields:

```
mappingid  varchar(200);
username   varchar(200);
createddate datetime;
openingBalance varchar(200);
```

and i have procedure to get opening balance of previous month of "monthint" and "yearint" :

```
getBalance(int monthint,int yearint)
```

I tried with :

```
select  *
from userBalance where userBalance.username='e00b6542-b5c6-11e4-aee9-00016c0fd125' and 
 month(userBalance .createddate) =(select DATE_SUB(month(userBalance .createddate),INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

But by specifying `month()` , not getting data from table.

Please help me out.

Comment: How your data is stored in DB. What is the datatype of the column. Provide table structure and some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *  from tbl_usertask
where userBalance.username='e00b6542-b5c6-11e4-aee9-00016c0fd125' and
month( DATE_SUB(userBalance.createddate,INTERVAL -1 MONTH))=monthint and
year( DATE_SUB(userBalance.createddate,INTERVAL -1 MONTH))=yearint;
```

?Using this query i got output as expected. Thank you